# Flex: how is loose coupling achieved by using interfaces?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop, flex3

Ive looked this up in a few different locations, but to be honest, i dont really get it. I get what loose coupling is, but not how interfaces in Flex would help to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general best-practice in OOP, programming to interfaces is not tied to a particular programming language. Flex or not, when objects are typed to interfaces (or abstract classes) they can more easily be replaced with alternative implementations.

Comment: Ok, just got it from this tutorial on Adobes site: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/dependency_injection.html

Comment: +1. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle for further reading.